# Split a random number generator in two

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's assume that we have a sequence Xn of numbers drawn from a uniform distribution on (0,1). Can I, for example, split sequence in two, x1, x3, x5,... (odd indexes) and x2, x4, x6... (even indexes) and treat two sequences as observations of two independent random variable (uniformly distributed over (0,1) )?

UPD.

I will try to reformulate the original question. Given a random number generator X which produces uniformly distributed numbers (on(0,1)) can i make two random number generators Y1 and Y2 considering each first number from X as a number, generated by Y1 and each second as generated by Y2?

Comment: Yes, but if if your random number generation has finite precision then you halve that with your method.  Depending on the way your (pseudo-)random numbers are produced you may also risk unexpected correlation which has not been previously tested

Comment: So if I have "ideal" random generator, splitting sequence it produces in several and treating them as mutually independent random numbers is fine?
Can you reference some theory on this subject, because, I , frankly, feel like I like formal definition of what  a random number is and how to formally describe the splitting process.

Comment: but if I just put even (by order) numbers into one set and odd into another one?

Comment: Yes,.that is OK for an ideal generator. Of course, the usual method of 'splitting' is to take the first and second half of the output. If you run a simulation twice this is essentially what you are doing. The goal is to have pseudorandom numbers that are independent and identically distributed as $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ // If you doubt your generator, you might try an ACF (autocorrelation function) plot of the sequence before splitting. Also plot the odd against the even values against each other and see if the unit square is filled uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to vet a pseudorandom generator. Here are two.
The series $U$ is generated by a faulty linear congruential generator
of the form $r_{i+1} = ar_i + b\; (\text{mod}\, d),$ with $a = 1093,\,$ $b=252,\,d=86436, r_1 = 6,$ and $u_i = (r_i + .5)/d$. The series $V$ is generated
by the Mersenne Twister generator, which is the default in R statistical
software.

The top-left panels shows simulated coin tosses converging too regularly and
quickly to a relative frequency above $1/2.$ At top right we see that
points $(u_i, u_{i+1})$ lie on relatively few lines in the unit square.
Perhaps worse, there are only 1029 uniquely different numbers in the $U$-series.
Any one of these three misbehaviors would caution against using this generator. By contrast, the bottom panels show good behavior of the Mersenne Twister.

[image]